# How to edit and delete data in table for each row fetched from database

Tags: php, button, search, html-table, edit

I'm  new to PHP and I hope to gain more knowledge from this site. So, I'm trying to make a project where users can search data online. I have successfully fetch the data and display it back for users in table form. Now, I'm trying to make edit and delete button at the end of the table row for each data. When users click on edit button, users can be directed to another page (form.php) with forms filled with the data fetched from the edit button row from the previous page. Meanwhile if users click n delete button, the data will be erased from database.

This is my code for displaying search result. I don't know how write code to put edit and delete button at the end of each row in the table.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "a14", "a14") or die("Connection 
Failed");
mysql_select_db("a14")or die("Connection Failed");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM jd_data WHERE fld_id = '$name' OR fld_pemilik LIKE 
'%$name%'" ;
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table border='2' >
<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
<tr>
<th>No Siri</th>
<th>Nama Perkakasan</th>
<th>Daerah</th><br>
<th>Lokasi (Kaunter 1,2,3/Back office)</th>
<th>Status (Beli/Sewa)</th>
<th>Tahun Perolehan</th>
<th>Perolehan JKSM/Negeri</th>
<th>Model</th>
<th>Os</th>
<th>Nama Pemilik</th>
<th>Catatan</th>

</tr>";
if ($result !== false) {
// use $result
} else {
// an error has occured
echo mysql_error();
die;    
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo "<tr><td>{$row['fld_id']}</td>
<td>{$row['fld_nama_perkakasan']}</td>
<td>{$row['fld_daerah']}</td>
<td>{$row['fld_lokasi']}</td>
<td>{$row['fld_status']}</td>
<td>{$row['fld_thn_perolehan']}</td>
<td>{$row['fld_perolehan']}</td>
<td>{$row['fld_model']}</td>
<td>{$row['fld_os']}</td>
<td>{$row['fld_pemilik']}</td>
<td>{$row['fld_catatan']}</td>

</tr>\n";
}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support coders, but this is not a free coding platform. You have to [do your research first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how). Try out how far you can get on your own. If you new here do the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it here. Check also what kind of [question should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and some of our [best practices](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/ask)

Comment: There are many resources out there for you to look for. You also shouldn't be practicing with such an old (unsafe) api. Try something then edit your post accordingly; we'll be glad to take a look at it then.

Comment: While this won't fix your problem, please note the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
. . .
<td>{$row['fld_catatan']}</td>

<td>
    <a href='delete.php?id={$row['fld_id']}'><img src='delete.jpg' /></a>
    <a href='edit.php?id={$row['fld_id']}'><img src='edit.jpg' /></a>
</td>

</tr>\n";
. . .
```

the same way you can add any button, which will take you to that page with id. You need to run delete or select query at that page.

Take some time to learn "crud operations with php mysql". Giving one tutorial, personaly not tested.
https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-crud-application.php
Also if it is not academic go for mysqli or pdo instead of mysql (now you are using mysql_xxx functions).